# get the lines that have date in comparing to the given date

Tags: date

I have a log file that has text (a list of filenames), which are of this format:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/us.ca.sf.release123.20170401164500025
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/us.ca.sf.release123.20170401170000022
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/us.ca.sf.release123.20170401171500018
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/us.ca.sf.release123.20170401173000018
```

Now, in a ksh script, I'm trying to retrieve two lists with the lines - one that have date OLDER date and other list that have NEWER date for a give date: 20170401 17:12

The first two lines into one older_list and last two lines into newer_list:
like,
older_list file has these:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/us.ca.sf.release123.20170401164500025
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/us.ca.sf.release123.20170401170000022
```

newer_list file has these:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/us.ca.sf.release123.20170401171500018
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/us.ca.sf.release123.20170401173000018
```

can you guys please throw me the script that can handle this.
our is an old version 
    oslevel
    5.3.0.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use for example `awk` tool in order to achieve your task:

Example:

```
> TIME=201704011700  # for same matter you could set it with current date TIME=$(date %Y%m%d%H%M)
> awk -F'\.' -v time=$TIME '{if (substr($5,1,12) >= time) {print $0 }}' your_input_log_file > fitered_after_$TIME
> awk -F'\.' -v time=$TIME '{if (substr($5,1,12) <  time) {print $0 }}' your_input_log_file > fitered_before_$TIME
```

Explanation:

1. TIME is an variable defined in your shell
2. `awk` parameter `-F`
   will define the `.` as a field delimiter thus your field we are
   interested in as per your example would be `$5`.
3. `-v` option will
   define for awk a variable `time` before starting with the value of
   your `TIME` shell variable.

Comment: Hi vadimbog, yes, perfect, that was the simple and yet most perfect one/two line solution that I could ask for, Thanks a lot for all the detailed explanation.